# error 500 when sending json from asp.ney ctrl to angular

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, json

im trying to make app where need to show data from db. But i have problem when sending data from asp.net controtller to angular http.get service. And i have **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**
My controller:

```
public JsonResult JsonShowAll() {
    var jsondata = db1.People.ToList<People>();
    return Json(jsondata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My js file:

```
var userApp = angular.module("UserApp", []);
userApp.controller("UserController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/Home/JsonShowAll/').
    success(function (data) {
        $scope.people = data;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("response code: " + status);
    })
})
```

and view:

```
<div ng-app="UserApp" ng-controller="UserController">
    {{people.FName}} 
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/UserJS.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does your routing really expect an ending slash?  Or should '/Home/JsonShowAll/' be '/Home/JsonShowAll'?

Comment: i changed, but it doesnt help

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in JsonShowAll() and stepped through the code while its executing?

Comment: yes, wat i should to see?

Comment: Have you tagged your method with [HttpPost] or [HttpGet] in your API?

Comment: Why are you using JsonResult?  Its an MVC class but from the code you've provided it looks like you're not using MVC.  Am I correct?

Comment: If you are able to step through the `JsonShowAll` function in the controller (as @jbrown said) then you should be able to see what is causing the 500 error.

Comment: no, i use mvc. JsonResult was in example, so i decided ti try it but with ActionResult same exception. I tried to send particular element of db, and it worked, but when i sending collection(list) it doesnt =(

Comment: @ArtemDanchenko Can you post the full exception?